# How to change razr d3 MAC address?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, mac-address

I'm trying to change the MAC address of my razr d3, model XT915, android 4.4.2, but I didn't have success.

In my last try I was using busybox and the following command:
busybox ifconfig wlan0 hw ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX

The return is :
ifconfig: SIOCSIFHWADDR: Operation not supported

So I started to look for the nvram files and was able to find the file WIFI at /data/nvram/APCFG/APRDEB and edit my MAC address there. Unfortunately, it seems that the MAC address is set somewhere else.

Does anybody know if it is possible to change the mac address in this scenario and how?

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to change a MAC address every device connected to the internet has a unique MAC address which can not be changed. May i ask why you wanna change it.